# Replace with a wildcard and use the values of the wildcard in python?

Tags: python, regex, replace, wildcard

Is it possible to do a replacement with a wildcard and use the values of the wildcard in Python?

A simplified problem might look like this:

```
import re
txt = "Some text of SpaFrancein"
tx = re.sub("Spa.*in",'Spain and .*',txt)

>>> tx
'Some text of Spain and .*'
```

However, I would like to have 'Some text of Spain and France'

Comment: `re.sub(r"Spa(.*)in",r'Spain and \1',txt)`